# Azure Synapse File cannot be opened error

Tags: sql, azure, azure-synapse

We are trying to query data from an Azure Storage Account in an Azure Synapse Workspace through a SQL serverless built-in pool. This worked fine till yesterday when we got the following error `File cannot be opened because it does not exist or it is used by another process` with a link to the following Microsoft Documentation: [LINK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql/resources-self-help-sql-on-demand#query-fails-because-file-cannot-be-opened).

Today we investigated the error and tested the following things:

- With a different account we are able to run the same SQL script.
- In a different Synapse workspace we do not have any problems.
- All accounts are in the same Active Directory Group, so they all have the same access.

When we explored the Synapse workspace we found the *Monitor* tab and at the moment the error occured there are three failed SQL scripts. All the scripts have the same error: `Error handling external file: 'waitIOCompletion error. HRESULT = 0x80070003(offset = 0, bytes requested = 117621).'.`

Answer (score 0):

As per [this thread on Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/628177/index.html), the same issue had been faced by others also due to some internal error, but the fix was rolled out within 24 hours. The issue had been resolved and confirmed by the users in the same thread.